# passenger_set_header has no effect with Passenger and nginx

Tags: nginx, puppet, passenger, rack

*My primary  problem is  to get puppet  to work  with nginx+passenger,
which only  works when I  execute puppet  master directly but  not via
nginx+passenger.   I  discovered  however,  that  passenger  does  not
forward environment headers in my setup.*

To verify  this, I  created a  simple rack app  which just  prints the
environment it  gets from  passenger. The headers  I configured  to be
forwarded by  passenger are missing with  this app as well,  hence the
generic subject.

Here is my test rack app:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'

class EnvApp
  def call(env)
    response = Rack::Response.new
    response.write "**** ENV{} ***\n"
    env.each do |key, val|
      response.write key
      response.write " => "
      response.write val
      response.write "\n"
    end
    response.status = 200
    response.finish
  end
end

run EnvApp.new
```

The nginx config for this app:

```
server {
 listen                     8888 ssl;
 server_name                puppet puppet.scip.foo;

 passenger_enabled          on;

 passenger_set_header       X_CLIENT_DN     $ssl_client_s_dn;
 passenger_set_header       X_CLIENT_S_DN   $ssl_client_s_dn;
 passenger_set_header       X_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;

 root                       /tmp/scip/rack/public;

 ssl_certificate            /var/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet.scip.foo.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key        /var/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet.scip.foo.pem;
 ssl_crl                    /var/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem;
 ssl_client_certificate     /var/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem;
 ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!RC4:!\
                            MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
 ssl_verify_client          on;
 ssl_verify_depth           1;
 ssl_session_cache          shared:SSL:128m;
 ssl_session_timeout        5m;
}
```

And the `http` section of nginx:

```
 # log ssl_client vars as well
 log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                'SSLDN:"$ssl_client_s_dn" SSLVR:"$ssl_client_verify"';

 # Passenger needed for puppet
 passenger_root  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3/gems/passenger-5.1.8;
 passenger_ruby  /usr/local/bin/ruby;
 passenger_max_pool_size 15;

 # passenger logging, 0=crit only, 3=default, 7=max
 passenger_log_level 3;
 passenger_log_file  /var/log/passenger.log;

 # Rack test app (that's the file posted below):
 include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/env.conf;
```

I am using  the same CA and  certs used by puppet clients,  so I leave
this part  here.  Just  for the  record: they work  and are  ok, since
puppet agents work pretty well  with puppet master w/o passenger using
those certs.

So, here's how I access the said app:

```
curl --cert /tmp/scip/srv2202.pem --cacert /tmp/scip/ca.pem -k https://127.0.0.1:8888
```

And this is the output (I broke up the rack.hijack line though):

```
 **** ENV{} ***
 REQUEST_URI => /
 PATH_INFO => /
 SCRIPT_NAME => 
 QUERY_STRING => 
 REQUEST_METHOD => GET
 SERVER_NAME => 127.0.0.1
 SERVER_PORT => 8888
 SERVER_SOFTWARE => nginx/1.12.1 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8
 SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.1
 REMOTE_ADDR => 127.0.0.1
 REMOTE_PORT => 57534
 PASSENGER_CONNECT_PASSWORD => oJdXmatT3cTnKvJw
 HTTPS => on
 HTTP_USER_AGENT => curl/7.56.0
 HTTP_ACCEPT => */*
 HTTP_HOST => 127.0.0.1:8888
 rack.version => [1, 2]
 rack.input => #<PhusionPassenger::Utils::TeeInput:0x00000008033ac950>
 rack.errors => #<IO:0x000000080317ab28>
 rack.multithread => false
 rack.multiprocess => true
 rack.run_once => false
 rack.url_scheme => https
 rack.hijack? => true
 rack.hijack => #<Proc:0x00000008033ac4f0@/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3/gems/\
                passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/\
                thread_handler_extension.rb:84 (lambda)>
 HTTP_VERSION => HTTP/1.1
```

As   can   be  seen,   there's   no   `HTTP_X_CLIENT_VERIFY`  and   no
`HTTP_X_CLIENT_DN`. However, I have enabled logging of those variables
in nginx and here's how the above request looks like in my access log:

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2018:14:15:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 873 "-" \
                "curl/7.56.0" "-" SSLDN:"CN=srv2202.scip.foo" SSLVR:"SUCCESS"
```

So, my  question is: how  in the world do  I get passenger  to forward
those two variables to rack?

My system setup:

- FreeBSD 10.3
- ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [amd64-freebsd10]
- nginx/1.12.1
- Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, one has to use dashes in the variable definitions, passenger then translates them into underscores. This setting works:

```
 passenger_set_header       X-CLIENT-DN     $ssl_client_s_dn;
 passenger_set_header       X-CLIENT-VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
```

Then in my env I get:

```
 HTTP_X_CLIENT_DN => CN=srv2202.scip.foo
 HTTP_X_CLIENT_VERIFY => SUCCESS
```

I'd say, this need to be clarified in the passenger documentation.